# Android Tabs Covering Collapsing Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablayout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

**Context:**

I have an AppBarLayout which includes:

- a collapsing toolbar, which contains:

  - a toolbar
  - an imageswitcher
  - a progressbar
- a linear layout, which will contain text views (a stripe of information)
- a tab layout

**Goal**

On scroll, the toolbar will pin to the top and the image switcher and progress bar will hide.

This currently works well when the image switcher is populated.
[**Screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaTCO.png)

**Problem**

However when the image switcher is empty, the tabs overlap the [**toolbar by a small margin**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2khGl.png) obscuring the icons and the title (if present, not shown).

You can see this as a screen recording as a link in the comments of this post.

**Code**

The code for the layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/scrolling-techniques-for-material-design&#x002D;-cms-24435 -->
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="@color/primary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:titleEnabled="false">


        <include layout="@layout/content_game_image_rotator"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:title=""/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white">
        <!-- Pin to top text goes here -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/game_detail_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/game_detail_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

The included layout (switcher and progress bar):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <ImageSwitcher
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/gamescreens"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ImageSwitcher>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/gamescreens_overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/screenshot_overlay_top_gradient"
        android:visibility="invisible">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/overlay_text"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:background="@drawable/screenshot_overlay_right_gradient"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/controller_support"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/multiplayer_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/singleplayer"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/coop"
                    android:contentDescription="Co-Op Game"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/multiplayer"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/compatibility_container"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ImageView android:id="@+id/compatibility_1"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_width="33dp"
                    android:layout_height="33dp"
                    />
                <ImageView android:id="@+id/compatibility_2"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_width="33dp"
                    android:layout_height="33dp"
                    />
                <ImageView android:id="@+id/compatibility_3"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_width="33dp"
                    android:layout_height="33dp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/switcher_progress"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Could you share your screen what exactly is happening.

Comment: @jaydroider I've got two links in the first post. [This one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2khGl.png) is the one showing the issue. I've also [got a .gif](http://i.imgur.com/yd5FtD6.gifv) which shows the working scenario (when the view can populate the switcher) and the overlap scenario when it can't. 
Hopefully that helps.